# pandas dataframe column means

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

```
  2000-01   2000-02  2000-03  2000-04  2000-05.....2016-08
   Nan       100      500      150      75          130
```

and so on. Each column is the year-month from 2000 to 2016-August.
I have my quarters defined as Jan-Mar:Q1, Apr-Jun:Q2, Jul-Sep:Q3 and Oct-Dec:Q4.

I am trying to convert this into a data frame that takes the average for each quarter, something that looks like

```
  2000-Q1    2000-Q2   2000-Q3   2000-Q4 .....2016-Q3
   200        75
```

where the values are averages for each quarter.
I think this should be a split-apply type of problem, but I am not sure how to achieve this in python...thanks in advance for your suggestion (newbie here :))

Comment: If you converted the column names to actual datetimes and then transposed so the columns became the index then you can just call `resample('Q').mean()` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks, the link worked perfectly...